# GMT time matching in c# mvc not working

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

GMT time matching in C# MVC not working.

Problems having fetch of time difference is not correct.

Here is the code I am tried but not working:

```
DateTime newDateTime = Convert.ToDateTime(DateNw).Add(TimeSpan.Parse(Time));
////New Zealand
string nzTimeZoneKey = Country + " Standard Time";
string date = newDateTime.ToUniversalTime().ToString("u");
DateTime localDateTime = DateTime.Parse(date);
DateTime utcDateTime = localDateTime.ToUniversalTime();
TimeZoneInfo nzTimeZone = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById(nzTimeZoneKey);
DateTime nzDateTime = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc(utcDateTime, nzTimeZone);
return nzDateTime;
```

The above code working for India and Afghanistan working very well but if I change the country between India and Fiji it is not working.

I want GMT time matching for all the country where I can differentiate two country time.
Any suggestion?

Comment: Why do you format the universal time to a `string`, just to parse it back to a `DateTime`?  Specifically when would `utcDateTime` not be the same as `newDateTime.ToUniversalTime()`?

Comment: this code is not working for indian vs fiji time.could u write down code for me

Comment: This --> Country + " Standard Time"; will not work. There are specific names/keys used to find time zone information. Tacking on a country to a literal the way you are doing will not work. You need to find a time zone name that falls in the area of the world you are testing.

Comment: Here Country  is dynamic... Fiji standard Time is coming worng

Comment: For India, what if the country was changed to Belize or Somalia?

Comment: Yes i want that type of code to change country gmt

Comment: Are you sure you want GMT and not UTC?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to look in the registry to find the appropriate Time Zone Name to use in your `TimeZoneInfo` conversionsc as Country + "Standard Time" make not always work.

The Key `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Time Zones` contains the names of all the time zones supported. Make note that Microsoft released information that Fiji recently changed their DST.

Are you are overcomplicating this?

```
string date = newDateTime.ToUniversalTime().ToString("u");
DateTime localDateTime = DateTime.Parse(date);
```

See if this works...If the `DateTime` is stored in UTC you can use some functions I added in the static class below.

```
    DateTime utcDateTime=ReadeFromDatabaseAsUTC();

    TimeZoneInfo localTimeZoneInfo=new TimeZoneInfo("New Zealand Standard Time");
    DateTime localDateTime= TimeZoneConversion.FromUTCToSpecificTimeZone(localTimeZoneInfo,utcDateTime);      
    localDateTime=localDateTime.Add(TimeSpan.Parse(Time));
    utcDateTime=TimeZoneConversion.FromSpecificTimeZoneToUTC(localTimeZoneInfo,localDateTime);  

    SaveToDatabaseAsUTC(utcDateTime);
```

Here is a handy class you can use to help with conversions :

```
public static class TimeZoneConversion
{
    public static System.DateTime FromSpecificTimeZoneToUTC(string specificZone, System.DateTime specificTimeZoneDateTime)
    {
        TimeZoneInfo fromZone = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById(specificZone);
        return TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeToUtc(specificTimeZoneDateTime, fromZone);
    }
    //--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    public static System.DateTime FromSpecificTimeZoneToUTC(TimeZoneInfo fromZone, System.DateTime specificTimeZoneDateTime)
    {
        System.DateTime temp = System.DateTime.SpecifyKind(specificTimeZoneDateTime, DateTimeKind.Unspecified);
        return TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeToUtc(temp, fromZone);
    }
    //--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    public static System.DateTime FromUTCToSpecificTimeZone(TimeZoneInfo toZone, System.DateTime UTCTimeZoneDateTime)
    {
        return TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc(UTCTimeZoneDateTime, toZone);
    }
    //--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    public static TimeSpan GetTimeZoneOffsetDifference(TimeZoneInfo oldZone, TimeZoneInfo newZone)
    {
        var now = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow;
        TimeSpan oldOffset = oldZone.GetUtcOffset(now);
        TimeSpan newOffset = newZone.GetUtcOffset(now);
        TimeSpan difference = oldOffset - newOffset;
        return difference;
    }
    //--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    public static System.DateTime FromUTCToSpecificTimeZone(string totimezone, System.DateTime UTCTimeZoneDateTime)
    {
        TimeZoneInfo toZone = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById(totimezone);
        return TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc(UTCTimeZoneDateTime, toZone);
    }
    //--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    public static System.DateTime FromLocalTimeZoneToUTC(System.DateTime localDateTime)
    {
        return localDateTime.ToUniversalTime();
    }
    //--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    public static string GetServerTimeZoneID()
    {
        return TimeZone localZone = TimeZone.CurrentTimeZone.StandardName;
    }
    //--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest simply setting the current time for each based on the timezone instead of changing the country:

```
var tzi = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("Pacific Standard Time");
var localDateTime = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc(DateTime.UtcNow, tzi);
```

Would doing this for each not work? 
There is no need for each to be directly connected.

Comment: var tzi = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("Fiji Standard Time");
                var localDateTime = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc(DateTime.UtcNow, tzi); this code is not working.fiji is 6:30 hr ahead from indian time.its coming wrong.

Comment: What are you ending up with for your TimeZone Info?
Using 'India Standard Time' should be fine.

Answer (score 1):

You should use standard timezones instead of trying to create one based on the country name.

```
ReadOnlyCollection<TimeZoneInfo> tzCollection;
tzCollection = TimeZoneInfo.GetSystemTimeZones();

Console.WriteLine(tzCollection.Count);
foreach (TimeZoneInfo timeZone in tzCollection)
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0} : {1} : {2}", timeZone.Id, timeZone.DisplayName, timeZone.BaseUtcOffset.TotalMinutes);
}
```

This timezone collection you can bind to the list or dropdown list. You can use DisplayName to show the names to the user and Id as value bound to each of the item in the list. and when  user selects the timezone you can locate the timezone from the collection using the Id of it.

```
var selectedTimezone = DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Value;
TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById(selectedTimeZone);
```

And once you have time information available you can carry on with your logic of conversion and other stuff.